# Programatically checking if field is empty in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

As part of a complex workflow which will involve several models in QGIS 3.2, I would like to check if all features in a layer resulting from a model's output do not have an empty value on a specific field before proceeding with the next model. In the event that I have a feature with an empty value on that particular field, I would like to get an error message or a warning message and stop the process.

I am fairly new to QGIS modelling and Python, and I am confused on how to proceed, as if I am not wrong there are several ways to accomplish it (python scripts, batch processes, post_hooks...). My guess is that I should create a python script and add it into my model as an algorigthm. The script should check if a all features within an input layer have a value for a field and if it is true it would output the same layer, whereas if it is not, it should display an error window, stopping the model.

Whereas it looks fine on my mind, I have do admit that I do not know how to code that script. I have read the template code for Python scripts (which is excellently commented) but unfortunately I haven't been able to create anything close to work.

Does my approach have sense? and if so, could anyone guide me with this?

Edit: I have checked QGIS API and I found this [`Class: QgsFieldValidator`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/Field/QgsFieldValidator.html) but could not understand how to use it.

Comment: Actually you can use the field calculator to check for empty fields: CASE WHEN "fieldname" IS NULL THEN e.g. call a pyhton script ELSE continue END

The point on how to abort the calculation using a python script is the rather tricky one I think.

Comment: Do you mean to use the algorithm "field calculator" within my model? if so, I do not know how call the python script.

Comment: The field calc can call userdefined functions, e.g. python scripts/code.

Comment: I see I can do that on the field calculator itself, but not on the processing algorithm (but it is possible that it may be right in front of my eyes and still can see it). Furthermore, I do not know how should I call a python script on my project's folder (eg: `/home/scripts/myscript.py`). could you guide me with that, please?

Comment: If you are using the graphical modeller, you can incorporate and field calculator operations there. As to calling on a python script: Sorry, can't help you there, haven't done it yet myself.